# Using relative XPaths to apply conditions to an already found element?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Say I have a button:

```
<button id="button" title="my button" />
```

I then store this button:

```
IWebElement Button = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("button");
```

I then want to check that the title equals "my button":

```
Button = Button.FindElement(By.XPath("[@title='my button']");
```

But this throws an exception that the element can not be found.

I realise that in this example I could just apply the condition in the first search, but in the real solution I can not do so. Is there any way to apply conditions to an existing element via relative XPaths?

Comment: Solved my own question with answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
Button.getAttribute("title").equals("mybutton"))
```

The above statement will return true if title of button is equal to mybutton.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `self::node()`, for example:

```
Button = Button.FindElement(By.XPath("self::node()[@title='my button']"))
```

Comment: You don't really want/need to do this. sai's answer is the better/proper way to do this.

Comment: @JeffC Sai's answer is too simplistic for my real problem. There are no nice attributes or ids in the real problem, so an XPath must be used.

Comment: That's not true at all. If this XPath works then so will sai's answer. You are referencing the title attribute in your XPath so it must exist.

Comment: In my real-world solution, I am trying to find a node based on the characteristics of a child node, like this:

`self::node()[.//a[text()='hello'] and ./div[@class='hi']]`

This could not be achieved with Sai's answer. I tried to simplify my question's example but maybe I made it too simple.